How do I update Discord on Ubuntu 24.04 to v 0.0.67?
I need help to fix this issue.
I don't know how to manually update Discord on Ubuntu. Discord doesn't work I have to update it to use it. Thanks in advance. I have Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.

How did you install discord?

Discord is a snap on Ubuntu 24.04 This snapcraft article explains updates.

You can also download it here from the Discord site or in your browser.

I have installed Discord through Ubuntu software store.

I was using the version 0.0.66 regularly, but now the system doesn't allow anymore if I don't update it.

@user535733 right now I've installed Discord from snap, and it has version 0.0.66. When I run it, Discord shows me a window with a message: "Update failed — retrying in 10 sec…", then "Update failed — retrying in 20 sec…", etcetera.

@GustavoHofman it's unclear what "but now the system doesn't allow anymore" means. Perhaps a mis-translation? Exact, complete error messages would be helpful.  Please edit your question to add new information or clarify. Avoid new information in comments. Comments are how we ask you for information and clarification.
